# C# Application does not crash in VS BUT CRASH on system running

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing a simple test tool to verify how many HASH(SHA1) the customer server can elaborate in 1 second.

The attached sample use muti-threading to start and stop a timer that counts executed HASH.
The HASHes are sequential.

The application works well in Visual Studio, but if I run it outside the VS environment it crashes.

The problem is on increment() function in "using" section. If I comment it, everything works well!

```
    static void increment()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] result;
                byte[] data = new byte[20];
                new Random().NextBytes(data);
                result = sha.ComputeHash(data);
            } 
            Interlocked.Increment(ref safeInstanceCount);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code used to start and stop the time is the following:

```
    bool stop;

    static void Main() 
    {

        try {

        TimerQueueTimer qt;
        qt = new TimerQueueTimer();
        TimerQueueTimer.WaitOrTimerDelegate CallbackDelete = new TimerQueueTimer.WaitOrTimerDelegate(QueueTimerCallback);
        uint dueTime = uint.Parse(textBox1.Text); // string "60000" = 1 min
        uint period = 0; 
        qt.Create(dueTime, period, CallbackDelete);

        while (!stop)
        {
        //    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(increment));
        //    thread.IsBackground = true;
        //    thread.Start();
            increment();
        }
        stop = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void QueueTimerCallback(IntPtr pWhat, bool success)
    {
        try
        {
            stop = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

How can I understand where is the error?

=

The application crashes without any exception.
I try to catch it, without success, it happened after 60 sec. (Maybe QueueTimerCallback is called?)

The application does not generate any error trace and it DOES not crash running under Visual Studio!
When it crashes it does not generate any stack trace, just a pop-up crash window giving in detail the "StackHash_xxxxx" error

Nothing to do! I've try to use Console.Read (it's a Windows app not console) but I cannot see anything. Here is the error shown!                                                                                              https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/iHsBhRSy-DNTYVo4CpoeA9MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Comment: Looking at the exception and stack trace would be a nice start.

Comment: Isn't that what the point of the Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); is there for? So you can see what is crashing?

Comment: And if uncatched exception spotted - there is event viewer.

Comment: Catching the exception is pointless, you're just masking the error. Remove the `catch` block and your app will crash when an exception is thrown. That crash message will tell you what went wrong, and where. It will also give you an option to break in with the debugger to look at the code.

Comment: "it's a Windows app not console"  Then `Console.WriteLine` is not the appropriate mechanism to show error messages.  The simplest is to use `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())` and/or write the exception out to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is likely throwing an exception, and it's getting written to the console, but you don't have anything from stopping the console from closing immediately after the message is written.

Add a `Console.ReadKey();` after your try/catch block.

Comment: @WaltZie If it's a Windows app then why are you using `Console.WriteLine`?  Why not use `MessageBox.Show` instead?